# Get datetime tibble as plain text

Tags: r

I have imported some data from an Excel Sheet to an R data frame in which some columns contain data and time in one cell like `2018-11-13 11:30:00`

When I try to print it in the console like `df[1,"Time"]` my output is

```
A tibble: 1 x 1
  Time              
  <dttm>             
1 2018-11-13 11:30:00
```

However, R doesn't seem to recognize it as a date & time, when I try to do further calculations, but handles it as a number
I need to compare this to date & time from something from another database (not in Excel), which is set up in exactly date format like `2018-11-13 11:30:00`

Hence, I would like to just read the entry of my dataframe/tibble as a text string saying `2018-11-13 11:30:00` so I can compare when they show the same time.
Using the toString or as.character functions doesn't work. It just gives

```
toString(df[1,"Time"])
[1] "1542108600"
as.character(df[1,"Time"])
[1] "1542108600"
```

I think the tibble thing is the problem.
How can I make R read the tibble this way?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.
Simply use the function `deframe` it turns it from a tibble into a normal value.

```
deframe(df[1,"Time"])
[1] "2018-11-13 11:30:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform it to string you can simply do:

```
df[1,"Time"] = as.character(df[1,"Time"])
```

But you can format it to date, you just need to say what is the format of it:

```
date = "2018-11-13 11:30:00"
date = as.POSIXct(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: No, it's same problem as toString. I think it's because it's in a tibble.
```
as.character(df[1,"Time"])
[1] "1542108600"
```

Comment: It looks like your tibble is already formatted like date, the header from it says `<dttm>`, and this number is a way to define dates as the number of seconds passed since a fixed date (i don't know which). So if it's already formatted as date, what went wrong when trying to compare with the other database?

Comment: If only I knew. When I ask `class(df[1,"Time"])` I get `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` So I think the problem is the classes don't match

Comment: If I try to save the two dates that should match I get
Warning message:
In isTRUE(mydate1 == mydate2) :
  Incompatible methods ("==.POSIXt", "Ops.data.frame") for "=="

Comment: Try to post the two datasets that you have in your post, so i can understand better their formats. Use the `dput` function.